# Magento 1 Tax calculation in order creation and invoice creation off by one cent

Tags: magento-1.9, taxes, tax-rounding

Let's assume we create an oder. The full tax report says that the individual tax rate is 19% and the *individual tax amount* is **78.84 €**. The *total tax amount* is **78.84 €** as well.

Now we create the invoice. If we take a look at the Invoice totals the individual tax is off by one cent (**78.83 €**) and does not match the total tax amount anymore.

[image: Order Totals vs. Invoice Totals Screenshot]

This is especially problematic since the differing tax amounts (individual vs. total) are on the receipt (pdf) as well.

I can provide you with the tax calculation settings as well, but I hope I do not have to change them since everything else seems to work out fine (finally).

[image: Screenshot of tax calculation settings]

Any help on how to unify the tax calculation throughout the whole process (order creation, invoice creation)?

I do not dare to ask why the Subtotal is different as well...